# Anaconda install used all space, how to free up space again?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I created a conda environment and started installing anaconda, but quickly noticed the size of the library was too big and stopped the install, after having used up around 2 GB of space.

I removed the environment with all installed packages using

```
conda env remove -n myenv
```

and then ran

```
conda clean --all
```

but my system is still running out of space. I could not free the ~2GB that got used during the anaconda install.

How can I proceed to restore that space?

Comment: For future reference, [Miniconda](https://conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) is the package manager only version, and let's one be more selective about what exactly get's installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to completely uninstall Anaconda if you want to free up that space. Follow the instructions on the Anaconda documentation 
[here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) to uninstall it.